# Using Node JS worker threads for I/O intensive operation and make use of multiple core CPU

Tags: node.js, multithreading, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

How effective is using worker threads for an I/O intensive application?
Context- I am developing an application which sends out multiple API requests in parallel. There is a limit of how many requests I can process in parallel as I need to calculate response time of every request. An increase in concurrency level would mean response time of each request will get more and more skewed as Event loop is sharing the processing of multiple tasks.

Can i make this system multi-threaded and utilize node JS worker threads. Can node utilize multiple CPU threads (I am using a 4 core CPU containing 8 threads total) and thus increase effective number of requests. For 8 CPU threads, Can i spawn 7 worker threads which can each handle X amount of requests and total number of requests (I/O operations) can be 8X now? What other factors should i consider here ?

Comment: You're unlikely to see any performance gains for this specific application. The skew you're theorizing is so small that it is unlikely that you'd be able to measure any difference. You can try though and compare the performance of the two techniques...

Comment: Have you actually tried how many concurrent requests you can handle in a single Node.js process/thread?

Comment: ... I have to say though, that having actually developed similar software what library you use to make the HTTP (I assume it's HTTP) request really matter as some of them are really slow. I'm currently using `undici` for my `httpstress` script and can reach around 17k reques/sec on my macbook single threaded (https://github.com/slebetman/httpstress). I've also had experience trying the multi-threaded approach and had almost no performance gain

Comment: Note that the only task sharing is the calculation of response times which in my case was simply `var end = Date.now(); latencies.push(end-start)` (I used an array because I calculate the average response times every second) which is not a significant use of CPU. So as long as your API requests take milliseconds to respond (instead of nanoseconds) you have plenty of unused CPU time to run your calculations.

Comment: @slebetman Can you explain why do you think so? I can probably run thousands of parallel requests even when i use single threaded application but since i need to compute the response time of each request i am forced to keep it as low as 100. Consider amazon.com has response time of 100 ms but if I have 1000 parallel requests, EVent loop is handling callbacks for 1000 calls so my calculated response time for amazon.com might be 700 which is not correct. If I have multiple event loops i should be able to actually run 300 in parallel?

Comment: @robertklep I can handle thousands of them. But then response time of each request comes out to be way more than what it would be when I fire a single request. For example an endpoint with actual response time of 200ms comes out to be 1200ms

Comment: How much CPU is the Node.js process using at that time? Also, can you elaborate what "compute the response time" actually means? I would think it's as simple as what @slebetman is saying (end time - start time). I don't see why that would have a big impact on the number of parallel requests.

Comment: CPU usage is about 30%. Yes response time is calculated as endTime - startTime.

Comment: CPU usage is about 30%. I don't think CPU consumption is the problem. Yes response time is calculated as endTime - startTime. But when i only have one request it is very less but when i have multiple promises for every endpoint in my queue, I see some difference. For reference, 200ms when just one HTTP request. When 100s of them it is 300ms. When 500 it is as high as 600. I am using native https module and i get start time before http.get call and end time is calculated when 'end' event is received. Duration is difference ofcourse Could it be network bandwidth or this is expected ? @robertklep

Comment: No matter how much CPU you throw at the problem you need to remember that your network card (and ultimately your router if the server is somewhere else) only sends one bit at a time: high, low, low, high, high etc. So if you have multiple parallel requests they will be queued (along with any other network activity like your OS checking for updates). If your network card is 10Gbps then it can send roughly 1 Giga Bytes each second. Assuming a HTTP request is around 1kB that limits you to roughly 1000 requests per second before you start increasing latency..

Comment: .. You can plug in other numbers to calculate your specific network setup. I typically calculate with 10 bits per byte 1. for simplicity but 2. to take into account overhead of the PHY layer (typical SERDES/UART adds a start bit and an end bit for each frame which is commonly bytes, Ethernet adds a preamble to allow the analog front-end to sync etc.)